# Remove one or more fields, delimited by a "-", at end of line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am going to parse data **googleapis.txt**

```
bucket,abc-def-ghi-45gjd4-wwxis
bucket,dde-wwq-ooi-66ciow-po22q
instance,jkl-mno-1-zzz-68dkakw-oo9w8
disk,pqr-stu-10-kuy-l2oxapw-rp4lt
```

I expect the result like these below

```
bucket,abc-def-ghi
bucket,dde-wwq-ooi
instance,jkl-mno-1-zzz
disk,pqr-stu-10-kuy
```

I am thinking that i have to change `-` to be a space  and then run this command

```
cat googleapis.txt | awk '{$NF="";sub(/[ \t]+$/,"")}1' | awk '{$NF="";sub(/[ \t]+$/,"")}1'
```

I got that from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27794421/8162936
After parsed, i will change the space  to be a hypen `-` back.

Does anyone know the best practice or one-liner shell command to parse it ?
Thanks all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

with `sed` you can do:

```
sed -E 's/(-[^-]*){2}$//' infile
```

match a pattern like `-anything` twice `(...){2}` from end `$` of every line and remove it.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ sed 's/-[[:alnum:]]*-[[:alnum:]]*$//' file
bucket,abc-def-ghi
bucket,dde-wwq-ooi
instance,jkl-mno-1-zzz
disk,pqr-stu-10-kuy
```

This uses `sed` to match the last two dash-delimited substrings on each line and remove them.  `[[:alnum:]]` will match any alphanumeric character.

You may shorten it down to

```
sed 's/\(-[[:alnum:]]*\)\{2\}$//' file
```

i.e., match and delete two sets of `-[[:alnum:]]*` ath the end of each line.

With GNU `awk`, you could also do

```
$ awk -F '-' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { NF -= 2; print }' file
bucket,abc-def-ghi
bucket,dde-wwq-ooi
instance,jkl-mno-1-zzz
disk,pqr-stu-10-kuy
```

but changing `NF` like this is not portable, and should be avoided (there's no guarantee that it changes the current record). It would not work with BSD `awk`, for example.

With standard `awk`, without resorting to using `sub()` (which would be to just mimic `sed`), you would have to recreate the current record from the fields that you'd want to use (in our case, all but the last two dash-delimited fields):

```
$ awk -F '-' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { nf = split($0,a) - 2; $0=""; for (i=1; i<=nf; ++i) $i = a[i]; print }' file
bucket,abc-def-ghi
bucket,dde-wwq-ooi
instance,jkl-mno-1-zzz
disk,pqr-stu-10-kuy
```

Answer (score 4):

With `rev` and `cut`:

```
rev file | cut -d'-' -f3- | rev
```

Reverse the lines, `cut` field 3 to the end of the line and reverse the text back again.

---

With `grep` (and PCRE):

```
grep -Po '.*(?=(-[^-]*){2}$)' file
```

- `-P` use perl-compatible regular expressions with a positive lookahead `(?...)` containing two matches of `-` followed by any non-`-` characters
- `-o` print only matched parts

Answer (score 4):

```
$ perl -F- -lane 'print join "-", @F[0..($#F-2)]' googleapis.txt
bucket,abc-def-ghi
bucket,dde-wwq-ooi
instance,jkl-mno-1-zzz
disk,pqr-stu-10-kuy
```

This autosplits each input line into array `@F`, using delimiter `-`.

Then it prints an array slice of all but the last two fields, re-joined with `-` characters.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it various ways as shown here:

```
$ perl -F- -pale '$"="-";$#F-=2;$_="@F"' file
```

Split the lines on a dash, set the array element joiner to dash, clip the last two elements, and set the current line to array joined with dashes.

```
$ awk -F- '{
   t = $1
   for ( i=2; i<NF-1; i++ ) t = t FS $i
   $0 = t
}1' file
```

This is with plain string processing:

```
$ perl -lne 'print substr($_, 0, rindex($_,"-",-1+rindex($_,"-")))' file
```

.

```
$ sed -ne '
   y/-/\n/
   :a;h;s/\n/-/;/\n.*\n/ba
   g;P
' file
```

**Results:**

```
bucket,abc-def-ghi
bucket,dde-wwq-ooi
instance,jkl-mno-1-zzz
disk,pqr-stu-10-kuy
```